# External Storage Permission Issue with MediaProvider / Ring Tones

Tags: android, ringtone, android-permissions, securityexception

Some of my users have reported to Google Play the following error when trying to select a ringtone in my app. (there's more to it, but it's not relevant)

```
java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: 
reading com.android.providers.media.MediaProvider 
uri content://media/external/audio/media 
from pid=5738, uid=10122 requires android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
```

I assume this issue is happening due to certain tones that are on external storage. I don't want to include the `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission in my app unless I absolutely have to.

Is there a way to circumvent the issue and just exclude any tones that may be on the external storage?

Note: I'm getting ringtones with `RingtoneManager` and convert them between `String` and `Uri`. No other code is touching the user's media.

Also, I do not have a line number since the stacktrace is from obfuscated code and re-mapping the stack trace did not provide line number.

Comment: can you post your code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just had the same problem and came up with the following solution:

```
private Cursor createCursor()
{
    Uri uri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;

    String[] columns = new String[]
    {
        MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID,
        MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE,
        MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE_KEY
    };

    String filter = createBooleanFilter(MediaStore.Audio.AudioColumns.IS_ALARM);
    String order = MediaStore.Audio.Media.DEFAULT_SORT_ORDER;

    return getContext().getContentResolver().query(uri, columns, filter, null, order);
}

private String createBooleanFilter(String... columns)
{
    if(columns.length > 0)
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.append("(");
        for(int i = columns.length - 1; i > 0; i--)
        {
            sb.append(columns[i]).append("=1 or ");
        }
        sb.append(columns[0]);
        sb.append(")");
        return sb.toString();
    }
    return null;
}
```

To get the Uri of a ringtone you need to combine the `INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI` with the `_ID` column value, you can do this by using `ContentUris` class:

```
Uri uri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(MediaStore.Audio.Media.INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, cursor.getLong(0));
```

Comment: I haven't tested it, but that looks like it will work.

Comment: I've tested it in 4.4.4 and checked against the sources of 4.0.3, so it should work with API 15 and upwards

Answer (score 2):

You can find the external storage directory without needing `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` or `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` by using `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()`.

You can then compare the paths for the URIs provided by `RingtoneManager` to this path to see if they are on the external storage or not and if so add those items to a `List`.

Then, rather than passing the raw `Cursor` to the UI you can use that `List` with a `ListAdapter` instead.

For example (untested, you may need to change the method of comparing paths):

```
class RingtoneDetails
{
    public String ID;
    public String Title;
    public Uri Uri;

    public RingtoneDetails(String id, String title, Uri uri)
    {
        ID = id;
        Title = title;
        Uri = uri;
    }
}

private List<RingtoneDetails> getNonExternalRingtones(RingtoneManager manager)
{
    List<RingtoneDetails> ringtones = new List<RingtoneDetails>();
    Cursor cursor = manager.getCursor();
    String extDir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();

    while (cursor.moveToNext()) 
    {
        String id = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(RingtoneManager.ID_COLUMN_INDEX));
        String title = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(RingtoneManager.TITLE_COLUMN_INDEX));
        Uri uri= cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(RingtoneManager.URI_COLUMN_INDEX));

        if(!uri.getPath().contains(extDir))
        {
            ringtones.add(new Ringtone(id, title, uri));
        }
    }

    return ringtones;
}
```

Comment: I think the OP specifically wants to know if this can be done by using `RingtoneManager`

Comment: `RingtoneManager` just lets you query the various different media providers, and from the get URIs or the `Ringtone` objects themselves.

I'm suggesting he makes use of `RingtoneManager` to perform the initial query, and then filters the results from that before requesting the `Ringtone` objects so that he's not making requests for `Ringtone` objects on the external storage.

Edited my original answer to make this clearer.

Comment: Yes of course, but the whole purpose (and cleaner solution) would be if you could filter *before* you pick something. It's quite user unfriendly to let them choose a ringtone and then toast a message saying "sorry that was on the sdcard, please choose a new one!"

Comment: Then perform the filtering of the results from `RingtoneManager` before returning them to the UI.

Comment: I am wanting to know if I can use RingtoneManager to exclude tones on the external storage so those are not in the list returned by `setSingleChoiceItems(cursor, position, c.getColumnName(RingtoneManager.TITLE_COLUMN_INDEX)` along with a brief example or a useful link that would help me with this.

Comment: Can you confirm how you are creating the `cursor` object for your call to `setSingleChoiceItems()`?

Comment: I am getting the cursor with `ringtoneManager.getCursor()`

Comment: Edited my answer to (hopefully) cover what you're after.

Comment: I havent tested it yet, but it appears that if anything will do the trick itll be this. thank you.

Comment: I just looked over my stacktraces again, and the exception is actually being thrown at `at android.media.RingtoneManager.getMediaRingtones(RingtoneManager.java:510)
at android.media.RingtoneManager.getCursor(RingtoneManager.java:372)` which means I can't analyze the cursor to exclude items on the external storage.

Answer (score 2):

Previously, I was using `RingtoneManager` to get a list and display that in a dialog for a user to select. It was throwing the `SecurityException` on `ringtoneManager.getCursor();`

I did not want to add the external storage permission, so I switched to doing:

```
final Intent intent = new Intent(RingtoneManager.ACTION_RINGTONE_PICKER);
intent.putExtra(RingtoneManager.EXTRA_RINGTONE_TITLE, "Select Ringtone");
intent.putExtra(RingtoneManager.EXTRA_RINGTONE_SHOW_SILENT, true);
intent.putExtra(RingtoneManager.EXTRA_RINGTONE_SHOW_DEFAULT, true);
intent.putExtra(RingtoneManager.EXTRA_RINGTONE_TYPE,RingtoneManager.TYPE_ALL);
startActivityForResult( intent, RINGTONE_RESULT);
```

And then in `onActivityResult`

```
if (requestCode == RINGTONE_RESULT&&resultCode == RESULT_OK&&data!=null) {                                                                             
    try {                                                                                                              
        Uri uri = data.getParcelableExtra(RingtoneManager.EXTRA_RINGTONE_PICKED_URI);                                  
        if (uri==null){                                                                                                
            setSilent(); //UI stuff in this method                                                                                              
        } else {                                                                            
            Ringtone ringtone = RingtoneManager.getRingtone(context, uri);                                             
            String name = ringtone.getTitle(context);                                                                  
            changeTone.setText(name); //changeTone is a button                                                                  
        }                                                                                                              
    } catch (SecurityException e){                                                                                     
        setSilent();                                                                                                   
        Toast.makeText(context, "Error. Tone on user storage. Select a different ringtone.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } catch (Exception e){                                                                                             
        setSilent();                                                                                                   
        Toast.makeText(context, "Unknown error. Select a different ringtone.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();             
    }                                                                                                                  
} else {                                                                                                               
    Toast.makeText(context, "Ringtone not selected. Tone set to silent.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();                  
        setSilent();                                                                                                    
}
```

Comment: but this line still causes a security exception: `Ringtone ringtone = RingtoneManager.getRingtone(context, uri);  `

Comment: @behelit, That seems strange to me. the docs for [`getRingtone`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/RingtoneManager#getRingtone(android.content.Context,%20android.net.Uri)) do not mention a `SecurityException`. It's been so long since I did Android, that I don't really know what I'm talking about though.