# always get java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial trying to read the data from external storage

Tags: java, android, exception, media

I am creating the media viewer app for android.When my app is running on mobile is works great, but when I run my app on tablet it crashes.I always get such exception:

> java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: reading com.android.providers.media.MediaProvider uri content://media/external/audio/media from pid=26136, uid=10096 requires android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, or grantUriPermission()

here is my code:

```
SortedSet<String> dirList=new TreeSet<String>();
Uri uri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
String[] projection = {MediaStore.Audio.AudioColumns.DATA};
Cursor cursor = null;
if (uri != null)
    cursor= context.getContentResolver().query(uri,projection,null,null,null);
if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
     do {
        String tempDir = cursor.getString(0);
        tempDir = tempDir.substring(0, tempDir.lastIndexOf("/"));
        try {
            dirList.add(tempDir);
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    directories = new String[dirList.size()];
    dirList.toArray(directories);
    directories=mediaFilter.filterMediaFiles(directories);
    if(!isInstalled){
        isInstalled=true;
        installAudioDetails();
    }
    return true;
}
}
```

manifest code:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.vasylpaliy.mediaview">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_WALLPAPER" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MEDIA_CONTENT_CONTROL"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_CONFIGURATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:largeHeap="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/gallery_icon"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/SelectTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:theme="@style/ImageTheme"
            android:label="@string/photos">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".ImageSelecter"
            android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/photos"
            android:theme="@style/SelectTheme">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.ImageSelecter" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".Settings"
            android:label="Setting"
            android:parentActivityName="com.example.vasylpaliy.mediaview.ImageSelecter">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.FullScreenImage" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".AudioList"
            android:theme="@style/AudioListTheme"
            android:label="@string/audio_list">
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".AudioAction"
            android:icon="@drawable/red_music"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"
            android:theme="@style/AudioPlayerTheme"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:parentActivityName="com.example.vasylpaliy.mediaview.AudioList"
            android:label="@string/audio_view">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
                <data android:mimeType="audio/*"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".ImageSlider"
            android:theme="@style/ImageSlider"
            android:parentActivityName=".ImageSelecter"
            android:label="Image">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <data android:mimeType="image/*" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.audioplayer.AudioPlayer"
            android:theme="@style/AudioPlayerTheme">
        </activity>
        <service
            android:name="com.audioplayer.AudioService">
        </service>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Just setting android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE to your Manifest may work.

Comment: I know, but it doesn't work.

Comment: can you post your manifest here ?

Comment: If you are trying it on Android M, be sure to enable that permission on App Settings.

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32350941/android-read-external-storage-permission-not-working) may help.

Comment: Oh, thank you very much, I will try it.

Answer (score 0):

set permission on **AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".Home"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".cst_cell_album_list"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_cst_cell_album_list" >
    </activity>
    <service android:enabled="true" android:name="com.vvs.root.memusic.PlayerService" />
    <receiver android:name="com.vvs.root.memusic.PlayerService$MyReceiver" >

    </receiver>
</application>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Answer (score 0):

By the looks of it you have set up the permissions correctly in your manifest. This crash might only happen on Android-M API23. The reason for that is `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` is considered a [Dangerous permission](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/security/permissions.html#normal-dangerous). So even though you have declared it in the Manifest, you need make sure to get the user to accept this permission at runtime. How to do this? Read here: http://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html

This is the right way to do it, but if you want to take the short way around, you could set the `targetSdkVersion` to 22 or lower. This will ensure that even when running on the M version, all permissions are granted. But still the user can manually turn off these permissions. So that's the downfall.

> Note: This lesson describes how you implement permissions requests on
>   apps that target API level 23 or higher, and are running on a device
>   that's running Android 6.0 (API level 23) or higher. If the device or
>   the app's targetSdkVersion is 22 or lower, the system prompts the user
>   to grant all dangerous permissions when they install or update the
>   app.