# I used Images.Media.insertImage for storing bitmap image but return null pointer exception below marshmallow device,in marshmallow device working fine

Tags: android

```
      public Uri getImageUri(Bitmap inImage) {
        ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        inImage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bytes);
        ContentResolver contentResolver = SceneActivity.this.getContentResolver();
    //this line return null even if i get bitmap image.
    String path = Images.Media.insertImage(contentResolver, inImage, "Title",null);
        return Uri.parse(path);
}
```

> I used above snippet to store bitmap image and return uri which is used to share image on twitter.

Comment: try with :  String path = MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(getContentResolver(),
                    inImage, "Image Description", null);
            Uri uri = Uri.parse(path);

Comment: it's throw exception below even if i give permissions for belowmarshmallow and marshmallow--- E/MediaStore: Failed to insert image
                                             java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: writing com.android.providers.media.MediaProvider uri content://media/external/images/media from pid=15949, uid=11381 requires android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, or grantUriPermission()

Comment: you have to set permission in manifest and also ask for runtime above lolipop

Comment: above lolipop working fine below lolipop not work this snippet

Comment: i try many below marshmalow device but not working this snippet,you have any oter idea to convert bitmap to uri and share to twitter?

Comment: i also try this :-   File filesDir =getFilesDir();
        File imageFile = new File(filesDir, "test" + "JPEG");
        OutputStream os;
        try {
            os = new FileOutputStream(imageFile);
            inImage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, os);
            os.flush();
            os.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(getClass().getSimpleName(), "Error writing bitmap", e);
        }
        Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(imageFile);
        return uri; -->but in this on twitter tost display image is not loaded

Comment: <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

    <uses-permission-sdk-23 android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission-sdk-23 android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

Comment: check this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/32351279/6756514

Comment: i try this one from above link -<uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
        android:maxSdkVersion="21" /> -->giving error -Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'.
> Manifest merger failed with multiple errors, see logs

Comment: post your build.gradle file

Comment: android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.3"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.goxal.restaurant"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 18
        versionName "3.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }

Comment: did your code working in Kitkat?

Comment: not workin,only in marshmallow working

Comment: i try out in moto e,moto g,samsung s5 but not work at all

Comment: Strange. i am using this code and it is working in every device

Comment: all have sd card?

Comment: some has.......

Comment: i suggest you to find other way.